# Joomla Get menu id from params

Tags: php, joomla

I have 2 parameters:
filter_town_id
filter_transaction_type

I would like to get the menu id contine the same parameters

Now I use a loop, but I think it is the best solution.

```
$menus = &JSite::getMenu();
$filter_town_id=$row->town_id;
$filter_transaction_type=$row->transaction_type;
for ($i=1; ; $i++)
{
    $params = $menus->getParams($i);
    $town = $params->get('filter_town_id');
    $type=$params->get('filter_transaction_type');
    if ($filter_town_id==$town&$filter_transaction_type==$type)
    {
        $itemid=$i;
        break;
    }
}
```

$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_component&view=view&id='.$row->slug.'&Itemid='.$itemid);

Comment: By what criterium exactly do you want to query the Itemid?

Comment: I need the item id for the url